# Has there ever been a fight between Iron Man and the Hulk where one of them won?

Tags: marvel, iron-man, the-incredible-hulk

I've been thinking about, and I've read spin-off stories that talk about who would win in a fight: Iron Man or the Hulk. Iron Man has technology and speed on his side, but the Hulk has brute strength and would be able to reach the height Iron Man does (as shown in the Avengers when the Hulk scales buildings as if it was nothing).

Has there ever been an answer to this?

Comment: http://www.comicbookresources.com/?page=user_review&id=7466 - Hulk beats puny tin man

Comment: The Hulk is pretty much indestcuctable, Iron man has many limits. So, the Hulk would win. His only real contenders would be Chuck Norris and Mr. T.

Comment: I'm unsure why this has attracted a "primarily opinion-based" vote to close. They've fought in various comics. It should be a simple matter to identify who won and why.

Comment: I could see an argument of *primarily opinion-based* due to the fact that it really boils down to who the writers feel like having win today (refer to the fights in Avengers vs X-Men for lots of nonsensical wins/losses), but since these battles have occurred, and are canonical, I see no problem with it.

Comment: Are we defining a "win" as either a knock-out/incapacitation, or merely that they stop fighting?

Comment: "Win" as in one of them renders the other incapable of fighting anymore

Comment: @phantom42 that was my fault, I don't know the canon that well :-(

Comment: A search of the internet should have revealed that Stark has never beaten the Hulk in a fight. Ever. For that matter, Stark always tries to fight above his weight class against heavies like Thor, the Hulk, Thanos and is regularly handed his walking papers with him often being peeled out of his suit like a tin can.

Comment: @Thaddeus - indeed. He's an arrogant sonofa@!#^* ain't he?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Iron Man and the Hulk have fought each other on a handful of occasions. The most brutal battle was during the *[World War Hulk storyline](http://marvel.wikia.com/World_War_Hulk)*.

Even with all of his technology and wearing the Hulk Buster suit, Tony is unable to stop the Hulk.

[ComicVine](http://www.comicvine.com/world-war-hulk/4045-42294/) explains:

> Iron Man dons his "Hulkbuster" Suit, in hopes of defeating Hulk. As the fight rages on, Iron Man, in a monologue, takes full responsibility for the incident, and explains that he knew that this day would come, as soon as he heard news that Hulk had not reached his destination. As they are battling, Iron Man injects nanobots into Hulk's bloodstream. This was supposed to slow him down, but hasn't seemed to take effect yet. After much fighting in the now empty Manhattan, Iron Man seems to have defeated Hulk. But, after a flashback of the death of his wife, Caiera, he only becomes angrier. He bursts from the crater his body had created, and dominates Iron Man.

The one-on-one ends with the Hulk victorious, and Tony's Hulk-Buster armor destroyed. The Hulk goes on to defeat the Fantastic Four, Doctor Strange, and everything and everyone thrown against him.

[image: Hulk vs Iron Man 1]

[image: World War Hulk Scan]

[image: Hulk vs Iron Man 3]

[image: Hulk vs Iron Man 2]

That red wreckage in those last two panels? That's Tony's Hulk Buster armor. Or... It was.

Comment: the nanobots are explained in avengers the initiative that hardball stole the nanobots and replaced it with a fake one so they could have work

Comment: IIRC, The Hulk stands up to The Sentry and wins (or at least is not defeated) in that arc.  And Sentry has pretty much godlike powers.  They've lately seem to emphasize that defeating Hulk by fighting him is futile because you just make him stronger.

Comment: @joshbirk Yes, I just didn't want to get too far into it for spoilers and since it was less relevant to the Hulk/Tony battle being asked about.

Comment: @joshbrick  if you fight hulk you have to defeat him fast or he gets stronger, but the sentry can easly defeat him in the world war hulk arc he didn´t use all his force he just free his power a little more

Comment: What? Sentry used up all of his energy trying to stop the Hulk. The Hulk remained standing and Sentry passed out. It's only because the Hulk *chose* to change back that Sentry didn't end up dead.

Comment: @phantom42 - agreed. Hulk basically gave up, otherwise he was unstoppable in that arc. It was shaping up to be an alternate Maestro origin the way we were going...

Comment: @phantom42, Ironman is now the winner  with the new hulkbuster: http://www.theverge.com/2014/10/24/7057313/hulkbuster-iron-man-vs-the-hulk-is-cool-and-poignant

Comment: @Pacerier Thanks for the spoiler.

Comment: @Pacerier Doesn't matter though. Question was about the comics, not the MCU.'

Comment: @phantom42, Are there huge differences between them?

Comment: @Pacerier given that Tony was effectively able to knock out the Hulk in the MCU using pretty much brute force, yes. That's never been done in the comics. Hulk should just keep getting madder and getting stronger.

Comment: @phantom42 the directors of MCU decided that they don't want an unbeatable Hulk - they want to keep the tension, and avoid a scenario where "X people enter battle, Hulk always wins"

Answer (score 4):

Hulk v Iron Man's latest, most heavily weaponised, Hulkbuster armour from this weeks Hulk v Iron Man. Hulk could do this to Ultron but for plot purposes they avoid writing a fight between them.

[image: Hulk v Iron Man Hulkbuster Armour #1]
[image: Hulk v Iron Man Hulkbuster Armour #2]
[image: Hulk v Iron Man Hulkbuster Armour #3]
[image: Hulk v Iron Man Hulkbuster Armour #4]
[image: Hulk v Iron Man Hulkbuster Armour #6]
[image: Hulk v Iron Man Hulkbuster Armour #5]

Answer (score 3):

Hulk wins.
Iron Man has made armors specifically designed against Hulk before; there is the Hulk Buster Mark I in Iron Man (vol. 1) #304, which was capable of lifting 175 tons but in Secret Wars  bannerhulk one of the weakest hulk forms lifted a montain which weights way more than 175 tons and the Hulk Buster Mark II was destroyed in a brutal battle in World War Hulk #1.

Answer (score 2):

Based on previous comics, the strength of the Hulk has always outweighed anything Stark can design, so he always wins

Answer (score 2):

Iron Man has won against Hulk before. In Iron Man #132 Iron Man put all of his power into to a punch and defeated Hulk.

[image]